# Load .blend file into Blender as Python Module

Tags: python, blend-files, scene

I am using Blender as a Python module.
Now I am trying to load a scene into blender.
Unfurtunately the obvious function `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath)` does not work as expected.
The command fails saying:

> Calling operator "bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile" error, expected a string
>   enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN',
>   'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA',
>   'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN',
>   'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA',
>   'EXEC_SCREEN')

Can anyone explain to me how to load an existing .blend file when blender is used as Pyhton module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general operator calling issue, not related to using blender as a python module.

From the [api docs on operators](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html#keywords-and-positional-arguments) -

> For calling operators, keywords are used for operator properties and positional arguments are used to define how the operator is called.

As you are giving a single positional argument it is interpreted by the operator as the `execution_context` value, which is meant to be a string from a defined enumeration of values, hence the error and the working solution that you found.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question.

Problem was, that Python misinterpreted the passed argument `filename`.
Assigning the argument filename as follows fixes the error.

```
filepath = "path\to\file.blend"
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=filepath)
```